# Excel VBA - Code to move or copy worksheets without warnings

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that would act the same as right clicking a *workbook* tab, selecting move or copy, checking the copy option, selecting another open *workbook* and clicking ok but without the warnings.  I found the code to disable warning and I was able to record a macro that does what I want but I don't know how to make it request which open *workbook* to copy to.

In short how do I make the following code work where **WorksheetIWantToCopy** is the one the user currently has selected and **OpenWorkbookIWantToCopyToo.xlsx** is a *workbook* to be selected by the user out of a list of open *workbooks*.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("**WorksheetIWantToCopy**").Select
Sheets("**WorksheetIWantToCopy**").Copy Before:=Workbooks( _
    "**OpenWorkbookIWantToCopyToo.xlsx**").Sheets(1)
```

I appreciate any information anyone can provide.  My team greatly appreciates your support (we currently have to hit ok on 25 warnings due to conflicts we don't really care about).  Thx!

Comment: don't you want to use the [Open Filename Dialog](http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/VBA/19208.html)? Btw, you could use the Excel object model and remove the `Select` line.

Comment: You'll need to show the user a userform with a list of open workbooks for them to pick from, or an inputbox with a numbered list and they can type the number of the workbook they want to copy the sheet to. Note: "worksheet" is distinct from "workbook" - any answers are more likely to be helpful if you avoid any confusion in your question (remember: you can edit it anytime)

Comment: Do you have any idea why the Application.DisplayAlerts = False does not prevent the name error from displaying?  I put the following code in both sending and receiving workbooks and the errors still display `Private Sub Workbook_Open()
MsgBox "Setting errors to false"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
MsgBox "Errors set to false"
End Sub`

Answer (score 1):

If the worksheet you want to copy will always be the active sheet then you can use `ActiveSheet`.

As for letting the user select a workbook, it can be as simple as using the InputBox.

```
Public Function getWorkbookName() As String
   Dim i As Integer, sListOfWbks As String, sRsp As String
   ' build list of workbooks
   For i = 1 To Workbooks.Count
      sListOfWbks = sWbkList & vbCrLf & i & " - " & Workbooks(i).Name
   Next i
   sRsp = InputBox("Select workbook." & vbCrLf & sListOfWbks)
   If IsNumeric(sRsp) Then
      getWorkbookName = Workbooks(CInt(sRsp)).Name
   Else
      ' user pressed cancel or entered invalid text
      getWorkbookName = ""
   End If
End Function
```

This basic example will of course list **all** workbooks, including hidden add-ins and the workbook you are moving away from.

Comment: Thanks mischab1.  This is a level above me.  Do you have any idea why the Application.DisplayAlerts = False does not prevent the name error from displaying?  I put the following code in both sending and receiving workbooks and the errors still display Private Sub `Workbook_Open()
MsgBox "Setting errors to false"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
MsgBox "Errors set to false"
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be said before anything else: always, **always, ALWAYS** make use of `.Copy` instead of `.Move` when automatically shuffling excel workbooks with VBA. `Move` has inherent risks because it is a modification of the other file, and if your code misbehaves then you could lose all of the data you're working with.

First of all, know which workbook is which, with no ambiguity:

```
Dim wkbkDestination, wkbkTemporary As Workbook
Set wkbkDestination = Workbooks("OpenWorkbookIWantToCopyTo.xlsx")
Set wkbkTemporary = Workbooks.Open("WorkbookIWantToCopy.xlsx")
```

Next, Copy your desired tab to your destination workbook, rename the new tab to prevent errors, and close the second workbook, without saving.

```
wkbkTemporary.Worksheets("WorksheetIWantToCopy").Copy Before:=wkbkDestination.Worksheets(1)
wkbkDestination.Worksheets(1).Name = "WorkbookIWantToCopy"
wkbkTemporary.Close SaveChanges = False
```

Naturally, depending on the exact controls you intend to use, there are lots of ways this code could be implemented. From your description it is somewhat unclear what exact problem you're trying to solve and whether this is a one-off event you're trying to accomplish for a given list of files, or whether this function is to be used on an ongoing basis.